# Unkillable apache2 processes

Tags: process, apache-httpd, strace, segmentation-fault

After upgrading from debian lenny to squeeze (apache2 2.2.16-6+squeeze4 and php 5.3.10-1~dotdeb.1), my apache processes started to exit with segmentation fault. It happens every 5-30 minutes (for 1 process), so it does not do any impact right now. Problem is that sometimes instead of exiting with `SIGSEGV`, they just go crazy and loop with 100% system cpu usage in `SIGBUS` error:

```
# strace -p27635
Process 27635 attached - interrupt to quit
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
```

They don't respond to `kill -9`. But when I run strace on the process after killing it, it just repeats the `SIGBUS` twice and then exits.

```
# strace -p27635
Process 27635 attached - interrupt to quit
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Why is the process unkillable without strace? How does running strace influence the process that it can exit?

(I know that there is probably something wrong with my setup of apache/php modules, but in this question I'm interested in the strange behaviour of the unkillable processes. I will ask another question if I am unable to fix apache/php.)

Comment: Obvious question, but did you reboot after the upgrade?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes I did :)

Answer (score 3):

First, check your RAM.

A process that doesn't respond to SIGKILL is a symptom of either a kernel bug or a hardware bug. When you haven't just changed your kernel, the most likely reason is that your RAM is failing, so check it. Kernel bugs can have subtle causes (such as using the wrong version of gcc) and manifest themselves subtly (such as working perfectly except that the X server wouldn't start — same true story). It's not very likely that your new kernel is buggy, if you're using the distribution-provided kernel that a lot of other users are using, but it could happen — possibly a rare bug triggered by a combination of drivers and activity patterns. Try another kernel.

There may also be a bug in Apache that causes it to crash, but if SIGKILL doesn't work, it's not Apache's fault.

Comment: I have ECC RAM and I checked using edac-util and I have no single-bit errors reported. I am using manually compiled kernel. During the debian upgrade I upgraded also kernel from 2.6.33.7 to 2.6.33.20. I will try now using debian's php instead of the dotdeb php (but dotdeb is used by many many websites, so it should be also stable).

Comment: The most common kernel "bug" for an unkillable process is that it's stuck waiting for a I/O device ("D" state in ps). like a disk that died, or a remote file-system that became unavailable.